# Angular 2.0 - converting promise chaining to Observables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactive-programming, angular, rxjs

I am converting an NG 1.X service to NG 2.0.

My NG 1.X service has promise chaining (simplified):

```
dataService.search = function(searchExp) {
      return this.getAccessToken()
      .then(function(accesstoken) {
        var url = $interpolate('https://my-api-url?q={{search}}&{{accesstoken}}')({search: searchExp, accesstoken: accesstoken});
        return $http({
          url: url,
          method: 'GET',
          cache: true
        });
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      });
    };
```

I want to convert `search` service to be an Angular 2.0 Service, using `http` and returning `Observable`. I prefer leaving the `getAccessToken` service untouched, as an NG 1.X service, which returns a promise.

I was thinking about using `Observable.fromPromise` on the old "promise" service.

How can I do it? How can I chain those two?

**EDIT**:

Just to clarify, I want it to be something like this:

```
dataService.search = function(searchExp) {
 return this.getAccessToken()
        .then(function(accesstoken) {
           //Here I want to use:
           // this.http.get(url).subscribe(() => ...)
          });
        };
```

Comment: `Observable.fromPromise(dataService.search)`?

Comment: This is obvious. My problem is how do I return this value from a function? I cannot chain it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should make `search` method return Observable object. Something like this:

```
dataService.search = function(searchExp) {

    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.getAccessToken()
            .then(accesstoken => {
                return this.http.get('data.json')
                    .map(response => response.json())
                    .subscribe(data => resolve(data), err => reject(err))
            })
    });

    return PromiseObservable.create(promise); // Observable.fromPromise(promise)
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question is how do I change the second promise to become an Angular 2.0 `http` which uses Observable.

Comment: You mean inner $http?

Comment: Just return observable as inner promise. Then do `return Observable.fromPromise(promise);`. See updated answer.

Comment: This is interesting. I tried it but then In the component calling the service I have: `dataService.search(data).subscribe((res) => //res here is an Observable!!)

Comment: Yea, my version won't work either. I set up an experiment that seems to work better. Check updated version. Here is a demo also: http://plnkr.co/edit/VPnCTXV6lVayIp4HJ8pV?p=info

Comment: This looks really cool. I'll try to adopt it inside my application. @dfsq - do you think that there is a better solution / approach for this situation? I am playing with upgrade from ng 1.x to ng 2.0 and I'm wondering if this situation (of chained services) is a bad practice from the first place. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 3):

I converted @dfsq's Plunker to beta.0.  `map()` doesn't seem to be available anymore without importing it (but we don't need it here).

```
import {Component, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {PromiseObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(private _http: Http, private _accessService: AccessService) {} 
  search(searchExp) {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._accessService.getAccessToken()  // see Plunker for AccessService
        .then(accessToken => {
          return this._http.get('data.json')  // use accessToken here
            .subscribe(res => resolve(res.json()), err => reject(err));
        });
    });
    return PromiseObservable.create(promise);
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, AccessService, DataService],
  template: `<h2>Data loaded</h2><pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  data: any;
  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) { 
    console.clear();
  } 
  ngOnInit() {
    this._dataService.search('test')
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.data = res; 
      });
  }
}
```

beta.0 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JXMyzqfFnM44BiJu67gM?p=preview)</kbd>